# "because of" and "due to" with an example

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know which sentence below is correct:

- **Because of** the heterogeneity of smartphone users and their immense base, the relevant users of our software are not really segmented by sectors or professions.
- **Due to** the heterogeneity of smartphone users and their immense base, the relevant users of our software are not really segmented by sectors or professions.

Comment: They're both fine. Why do you think one is wrong?

Comment: No, they can be both fine. I wanted to have a confirmation.

Comment: Solely in the context of the Question, either could be correct but neither could be close to affirmative, let alone'


 '… they can be both fine'.

Sorry and no, they can't 'be both fine'; n

However, both make it obvious that you're not comfortable with English… as emphasised by '… they can be both fine'.

Sorry and no, they can't 'be both fine'; never.

Further, whatever you wanted was not 'a confirmation…'

Can you re-phrase at least the exposition, if not the Question itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to say Due to. Rather relying on my linguistic instinct of course, but I will try to explain it logically. The first option is rather used for pain, for example.

Comment: Nothing wrong with either one. And where did "pain" come from?